# Should I clean the "compress your OS drive" from disk cleanup on window 10?

Tags: windows-10, window, disk, diskspace

Question image is on this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5V1j.jpg, sorry since i have not enough reputation to post image.

- I never compressed my drive, why there is "compress your OS drive"
  option over there?
- If i optimized my disk will it also compressed my disk?
- Where can i check the "compress your OS drive" file is located?
- What is resided inside this file?
- Should i clean that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll suggest to not compress your data unless you're seriously running out of space as it results in loss of power and speed. This is because after compression, each time you open a file it would need to be decompressed and re-compressed while closing, hence a major performance-hit.

A detailed explanation can be found here: [My SSD is running out of disk space, and I see that "Compress your OS drive" is suggested as a means to save some disk space.](https://superuser.com/questions/1406360/is-compress-os-drive-worth-it-on-ssd)

There is another article with interesting answers and might help you:
[How can Windows 10 function on as little as 32 GB of disk space?](https://superuser.com/questions/1011288/how-can-windows-10-function-on-as-little-as-32-gb-of-disk-space)

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually a file; it's the option to compress your `C:\` Drive. Do so and it will recover 17.1 Gigabytes worth of storage space by making any file capable of being compressed smaller.